# case insensitive search in regex

Tags: regex

How do i Search Case Insensitive from the string for particular pattern.

**Eg.**

```
/(?<!^)(\d+)(?!( )?%)(\s*GM)?/
```

in above example i want word **"GM"** to be a case insensitive

**String :**

```
HERCIL 5% OINT. 10GM TEST ----->output->10GM
HERCIL 5% OINT. 10gm TEST ----->output->10
```

Comment: add `(?i)` at the start, ie, after the regex delimiters

Comment: Thanks @Avinash Raj

Comment: or add `i` after the last delim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `i` as inline flag like this:

```
/(?i)(?<!^)(\d+)(?!( )?%)(\s*GM)?/
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/QybsmK/1)**